# What is the minimum value of the common area of region M and N?

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, triangles, area

> The region M consists of all all the points $(x,y)$ satisfying the inequalities $y\ge0,y\le x$ and $y\le2-x$. The region N which varies with the parameter $t$ consists of all points which satisfy $t\le x\le t+1\forall\;t\in[0,1]$, then find min(ar(M$\cap$N)).

**My Attempt:**

Region M is the triangle.

Region N is the vertical rectangle.

I think the intersection area will be minimum if $t=0$ or $t=1$. In between the area will be more.

So, the answer should be $\frac12\times1\times1=0.5$

The answer given is $0.75$

Comment: .5 looks like the minimum to me. .75 looks like it's the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the problem uses minimum instead of maximum, or the solution uses maximum instead of minimum. I've made a quick sketch of the problem. The area you care about is the intersection between $\triangle ABD$ and the region between the two vertical lines. When $t=0$ or $t=1$ you get half of the area of $\triangle ABD$, which is minimum. But if you want to maximize the area, choose $t=0.5$ so you get a pentagon, made out of two trapezes, each one with the parallel sides of lengths $0.5$ and $1$, and height (along $x$ axis) $0.5$. Then the total area is $$2\cdot\frac12(0.5+1)\cdot 0.5=0.75$$

[image]

**Note:** probably the way you might want to do it is to calculate the area of $EFBHG$ pentagon as a function of $t$, then minimize or maximize it.